# Zigbee routing algorithm

Tags: linux, routes, sdk, zigbee, mesh-network

My goal is to implement a routing algorithm for attack detection using packet delivery ration calculation on a Zigbee module(hardware). I would like to know if it is possible to implement this on popular zigbee modules like NXP, TI, SiLabs. I tried Digi Xbees already but can't find a way to modify the route discovery process. Any suggestions and ideas are welcomed.
Thanks.

Daniel Emehinola

Answer (score 0):

Zigbee is a standard that defines several layers and the implementation of these layers is usually provided by the chip vendors, which in order to ensure people do not mess with these implementations, they provide many of these layers in the form of libraries so customers of these chips only have to care about implementing the application or modify existing sample apps, being said that, you need to find a Zigbee implementation that is open source, otherwise you wont be able to change the behavior or the routing mechanisms.

Hope this helps!